# What can cause user names to disappear from admin pages?

Tags: 7, debugging, users

On an existing Drupal system I see a strange phenomenon; user names disappear from the admin/people page. I've disabled the [realname](https://drupal.org/project/realname) module but still it happens. How to debug such an issue?

[image: Blank usernames]

**Edit: Additional Information**

My admin theme is Seven, so I've added a code to print the options array:

```
function seven_form_user_admin_account_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form['accounts']['#options']);
}
```

The result: The username fields contains the following typical information:

```
<a href="/user/322" title="View user profile." class="username" 
xml:lang="" about="/user/322" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" 
property="foaf:name" datatype=""> </a>
```

[image: username options]

Comment: Make sure you have disabled/uninstalled all custom/contributed modules and check once again.

Comment: if your admin theme is a Seven then put seven_form_alter to the seven's template.php. What will be the output of dpm($form['accounts']['#options'])?

Comment: Thanks @xurshid29, I've added the requested outpout of dpm.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil, but uninstalling all modules is not an option - there are too many of them... The question is how to find the source of the error, not how to start from scratch...

Comment: @Druvision uninstalling the all contrib modules is expensive, you will loose all configurations.. I had this kind of issue: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84030/missing-operations-links. I didn't find any solution for that, but somehow problem was solved magically after 2 months. I don't even know how it was solved :)

Comment: Thanks @xurshid29, I've now added the information you requested...

Comment: @Druvision That form is created with user_admin_account() in user.admin.inc and results are fetching with this query: `$query = db_select('users', 'u');
  $query->condition('u.uid', 0, '<>'); ..... $query
    ->fields('u', array('uid', 'name', 'status', 'created', 'access'))
    ->limit(50)
    ->orderByHeader($header)
    ->setCountQuery($count_query);
  $result = $query->execute();` Debug the $result var and check users table... may be you can find something interesting..